# import App from './App';

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am trying react based on [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app). I'm new to react.

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**./App** in `import App from './App';` is not clear to me when and where is this created, is this done by babel?

**file strucutre**

```
my-app/
  README.md
  node_modules/
  package.json
  .gitignore
  public/
    favicon.ico
    index.html
  src/
    App.css
    App.js
    App.test.js
    index.css
    index.js
    logo.svg
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <div>myComponent</div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You have provided `App.js`

Comment: ./App is the file and i can have multiple classes in that file?

Comment: You surely can.

Comment: `./App` refers to `App.js` in the same directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### **tl;dr**

No, it is not done by Babel, instead it is done by **create-react-app** package.

All the files and folders in that folder are created automatically when you run,

```
create-react-app your-new-app-name
```

---

```
import App from './App'
```

The above line is used for importing the class you have written in the file `App.js` under the **same directory**.

Next, the difference between,

```
import App from './App'
```

and

```
import App from 'App'
```

Use the **first** if you want to import any **user defined files** and **second** for **importing packages**. As [Shubham Khatri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5928186/shubham-khatri) mentioned, for importing files, it is technically same if you did or did not use `.js` extension.

---

### The longer version

[create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) is a starter kit for people who are new to React or for who are lazy enough to build an app from scratch. What create-react-app does is, it will give you a minimal running React app with a solid folder structure. As given in their documentation, you can install that globally by giving,

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

After this whenever you want to create a new app, what you want to do is,

```
create-react-app  your-new-app-name
```

This will automatically generate a folder with all the files you mentioned.

---

Within the folder when you open the file `public/index.html`, you can see a line

```
<div id="root"> </div>
```

And on the `src/index.js`, you can find,

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,{}
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

If you are familiar with javascript, you may know that `document.getElementById('root')` is used to match any tag in HTML with ID as `root`. So the above snippet means that, they are rendering the `<App>` component of react to div with ID `root`. This is how React communicates with HTML page.

---

Rather that writing all the component codes in a single file, it is a good standard to write each components in different files. Here, `App.js` is a component that basically renders the text **myComponent**. For using this component in other files, you have to do two things.

1. Export the component from the file where it is defined. (`export default App;`)
2. Import the component to the file where it is used. (`import App from './App'`)

General syntax for import is,

```
import className, { functionName } from 'packageName'
```

or

```
import className, { functionName } from './path-to-file/fileName'
```

Note: It is that `./` which tells the compiler whether to look on to `node_modules` folder or the path you mentioned. Use that strictly when you need to import **user defined files**.

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Even I am a novice in reactjs and wanted to learn. this is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

When you import your Component like

```
import App from './App';
```

It will import your file `App.js` that is present in the same direcotry as `index.js`
In webpack configuration we specify which types of files babel needs to build and there if we specify `.js` or `.jsx`, it takes by default the extension of the file when we import it. we do not explicitly mention it. You can change your immport to be like

```
import App from './App.js';
```

which is technically the same.

The `create-react-app` npm package makes use of `webpack` to build your code which you can see from the `package/react-scripts/package.json` in the github directory